# Access Multiselect Form Field in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a multiselect in html file like this:

```
<select multiple id="mymultiselect" name="mymultiselect">         
        <option value="1">this</option>       
        <option value="2">that</option>       
        <option value="3">other thing</option>
</select>
```

When I access the mymultiselect field in flask/python via:

```
request.form['mymultiselect']
```

or by using the request.args.get function it only returns one selected item.  I've learned that to get all the selected items I have to add [] to the name of the field, like so:

```
<select multiple id="mymultiselect" name="mymultiselect[]">       
        <option value="1">this</option>       
        <option value="2">that</option>       
        <option value="3">other thing</option>
</select>
```

I can see by viewing the post data in firebug that this is working, but I anytime I try to access this field in flask/python it comes back as null or None.

How do you access these multiselect form fields that have "[]" at the end of their name?  I've tried appending "[]" to the field name in the python code as well but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You want to use the [`getlist()` function](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) to get a list of values:

```
multiselect = request.form.getlist('mymultiselect')
```

You do *not* need to add `[]` to the name to make this work; in fact, the `[]` will not help, don't use it at all.

Comment: This took me unbelievably long to find - debugging this it's not even clear that Flask is the problem, it's only when I found PHP's `[]` that I thought to search Python/Flask specifically.

Any idea why `get` doesn't return the list? I can't see any desirability in this behaviour at all... It's particularly odd as `get` returns the first element. Gah.

Comment: So what if there is only one element? When should `get` return a list and when a single value? The API is explicit here; `get` returns one value, always. `getlist` returns a list,always.

Comment: This is great, i was struggling with getting back all the listbox items and was getting None.

Answer (score 4):

[image]> In sometimes, If you are using Ajax POST method then check the parameter name in network tab.
Check the image attached that describes how to verify the parameter names.

In Flask view:

> you can access the list responce based on parameter name.

```
request.form.getlist('mymultiselect[]')
```

> or

```
request.form.getlist('mymultiselect')
```

Comment: There is already clear advice from @MartijnPieters not to put `[]` into the name.

Comment: That's a typo mistake. My point is you should make sure that the parameter name passed as you declared. Sometimes parameter name itself has the '[]'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get values as dictionary

```
def __get_form_data(self, method='POST', compare_with=dict()):
    # Get form MiniFieldStorage items
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={ 'REQUEST_METHOD' : method })
    # Convert to dictionary
    return { key.rstrip('[]'):form.getlist(key) if key.endswith('[]') else form.getvalue(key) for key in form.keys() if compare_with.get(key)!=form.getvalue(key) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example if you are using FlaskForm with SelectMultipleField:

Form:

```
options = SelectMultipleField("Choose your option", choices=["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"])
```

Python code to get the choosen option, if your select option2 for example:

```
choosen_option= form.options.data
```

The result will be ['Option2'], just add [0] to get the element inside of list

```
choosen_option= form.options.data[0]
```

the result will be

```
choosen_option = Option2
```